Why is my PDA derivation mismatching between client-side and runtime on Solana?
I'm developing a Solana dApp and encountering an issue where the Program Derived Address (PDA) computed in my JavaScript client does not match the PDA derived during program execution in Rust, resulting in a transaction failure.
Here’s how I’m deriving the PDA on the client-side:
JavaScript Code:
const [poolPDA, bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [Buffer.from('pool'), sortedTokenA.toBuffer(), sortedTokenB.toBuffer()],
  programId
);
console.log('Derived Pool PDA:', poolPDA.toBase58());

Rust Program Logic:
let (pool_pda, _bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
    &[b"pool", sorted_token_a.as_ref(), sorted_token_b.as_ref()],
    ctx.program_id,
);
msg!("Derived Pool PDA: {:?}", pool_pda);

Error Logs:
Create: address 57StLe37JtXh8ezucLFkU9BnDpVtw4q4vg4zUUjZxArs does not match derived address DaUE3ihbA54PA4MpGGsN4zuVvPjkhSXn2NC9B2DzJwpg

What I’ve Verified:

The programId matches in both environments (client and program).
Token addresses are sorted lexicographically before being used in PDA derivation.
The seeds used ("pool", token A, and token B) are consistent in both JavaScript and Rust.

Question:
What could cause this mismatch between the client-side and runtime-derived PDAs? Are there any additional steps I can take to debug or resolve this issue?

Please double check both program_id, sorted_token_a and sorted_token_b in both side. you can log about that and have to check these are correct. I've checked your code in my side and two PDAs are the same in both Rust and JavaScript.
Rust
 use solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey;

fn main() {
    // Example program ID (replace with your actual program ID)
    let program_id = Pubkey::from_str_const("GpgkZ5CWoGGWAWy3vTwLygvefP5Wu6eXKb52rrZieY9J");
    let sorted_token_a = Pubkey::from_str_const("37qckfT2UHo7TA5j5HXo8a4f8Ctqz3QHNEuQKYtqy16j");
    let sorted_token_b = Pubkey::from_str_const("6EfPk2Y5xNUGP6eGxvsHEVmGR2XqGi9zXwRxJ3RRMqva");
    // Example seeds (they must be slices of bytes)
    let seed1 = b"seed1";
    let seed2 = b"seed2";

    // Find the Program Derived Address (PDA)
    let (pda, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
        &[b"pool", sorted_token_a.as_ref(), sorted_token_b.as_ref()],
        &program_id,
    );

    println!("Program ID: {}", program_id);
    println!("PDA: {}", pda);
    println!("Bump: {}", bump);
}

JavaScript
const { PublicKey } = require("@solana/web3.js");  

// Static example inputs  
const programId = new PublicKey("GpgkZ5CWoGGWAWy3vTwLygvefP5Wu6eXKb52rrZieY9J"); // Example program ID  
const sortedTokenA = new PublicKey("37qckfT2UHo7TA5j5HXo8a4f8Ctqz3QHNEuQKYtqy16j");
const sortedTokenB = new PublicKey("6EfPk2Y5xNUGP6eGxvsHEVmGR2XqGi9zXwRxJ3RRMqva");


// Test the PDA calculation  
(async () => {  
  try {  
    const [pda, bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(  
      [Buffer.from('pool'), sortedTokenA.toBuffer(), sortedTokenB.toBuffer()],
      programId       // The program's ID  
    );  

    console.log("PDA:", pda.toBase58()); // Log the generated PDA  
    console.log("Bump:", bump);          // Log the bump seed  
  } catch (err) {  
    console.error("Error:", err);  
  }  
})();

Log:
Program ID: GpgkZ5CWoGGWAWy3vTwLygvefP5Wu6eXKb52rrZieY9J
PDA: 3kuVj6Cp5PbvtY7N4HHunR4EAJvfAKaeyZSiunDYN6m6
Bump: 255

PDA: 3kuVj6Cp5PbvtY7N4HHunR4EAJvfAKaeyZSiunDYN6m6
Bump: 255

